# Python problem: How to solve for a simple number in while function?

Tags: python

I want the program to continue asking for input until the correct answer (10) is given. I just started with while functions, maybe I cannot put elif demands into while functions?

```
x=eval(input('Put in number between 1 and 12 '))
while x>10:
    x=eval(input('Too high! '))
elif x<10:
    x=eval(input('Too low! '))
elif x==10:
    print('Correct!')
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: If you want to loop until 10 is input you might want to start with `while x!=10:`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
x = 0
while x != 10:
    print('Enter The Number')
    x  =  int(input())
    if x > 10:
        print('Too High')
    elif x < 10:
        print('Too Low')
    elif x == 10:
        print('Correct')
```

Comment: Welcome , you can close this question by marking it answered.